# Как сделать персональную страничку profile для каждого пользователя?

Tags: java

Я новичок и приложения для интернета делаю впервые.

У меня есть БД на удаленном сервере, `java`-апплет, `html`-странички (для красивости). 
Апплет встроен в хтмл-страницу. Cперва загружается основная страница (`index.html`), где предлагается войти/зарегистрироваться. Все данные вносятся в апплет, сверяются с БД и если пароль и логин совпадают (с данными в БД), то нас перекидывает на другую страницу (`profile.html`).

Проблема заключается в том, что на страницу `profile` можно попасть и без ввода логина и пароля. И хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы страничка `profile` была для каждого пользователя своя.

Как это можно сделать? Книги посоветуйте или, быть может, где-то есть подобный разобранный проект.

Заранее благодарен. )

Comment: ИМХО, апплеты не лучшый вариант для веба.. Смотрите в сторону php,python,etc.

Comment: вы не сможете сделать авторизацию с помощью апплета, - просто потому что не сможете передать из него сесию к странице. разве что сделать валидацию а потом форварднуть пользователя куда-то еще. но сомневаюсь что у вас получится. у вас 2 варианта: отказатся от апплета или же делать весь функционал в самом апплете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИМХО, апплеты не лучшый вариант из-за его старости. Посмотрите в сторону servlets, jsp, jsf. А еще лучше Spring/Hibernate.
Апплеты чаще всего используются в одной закрытой организации. Типичная среда использования - внутренние сервисы банков(тоесть, у всех одинаковая конфигурация машин, как пользоваться системой написано в жестких требованиях). Еще один момент - хэшируйте пароли в БД, и сравнивайте их.
Скорее всего, вам нужен простой сервлет, в котором будет проверка пользователя и пароля.